# Algorithm to assess differences in sequence between two lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, sequence

I am looking for an algorithm to compare two sequences.

Sequence A - will be a list of integer Ids in optimal order

Sequence B - will be a list of the same ids in an order that may differ.

I want to be detect the differences in sequence between the two lists.

and as such am looking for an algorithm to do this. I am wondering if this is a common problem that has been solved before

Comment: Have you looked at [DiffLib](http://difflib.codeplex.com/) (Disclaimer: I wrote the library). I don't like "click this link to find the answer" type of answers, so I'm not going to post this as an answer.

Comment: You could use [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), which is pretty good for identifying additions, removal or modifications of elements within two sequences

Comment: I also have these articles online, which culminate with a basic version of DiffLib: http://devdirective.com/post/91/creating-a-reusable-though-simple-diff-implementation-in-csharp-part-1 - again, not a good answer for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

As Julián Urbano suggested, Kendall Tau Correlation is a good measure to use. I decided to implement it in .Net using Linq. Here is my code, which implements both Tau-A (for data without ties) and Tau-B (which permits ties). The code assumes that your data has not yet been sorted, so it sorts it once according to Measure1 to get the first set of rank values, then it sorts it by Measure2 to get a second set of ranks. It is the ranks that are correlated, not the original data. (If the measure lambda function returns the original object unchanged, then you can apply it to ranks that you already have.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Math;

namespace Statistics
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compute the Kendall Tau Correlation of two orderings of values, a non-parametric correlation that compares the ranking
    /// of value, not the values themselves.
    /// 
    /// The correlation of the measures is one if all values are in the same order when sorted by two different measures.
    /// The correlation is minus one if the second ordering is the reverse of the first.
    /// The correlation is zero if the values are completely uncorrelated.
    /// 
    /// Two algorithms are provided: TauA and TauB. TauB accounts properly for duplicate values (ties), unlike TauA.
    /// </summary>
    public class KendallTauCorrelation<T, C> where C : IComparable<C>
    {
        private Func<T, C> Measure1 { get; }
        private Func<T, C> Measure2 { get; }

        public KendallTauCorrelation(Func<T, C> measure1, Func<T, C> measure2)
        {
            Measure1 = measure1;
            Measure2 = measure2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the Tau-a rank correlation, which is suitable if there are no ties in rank.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A value between -1 and 1. 
        /// If the measures are ranked the same by both measures, returns 1.
        /// If the measures are ranked in exactly opposite order, return -1.
        /// The more items that are out of sequence, the lower the score.
        /// If the measures are completely uncorrelated, returns zero.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="data">Data to be ranked according to two measures and then correlated.</param>
        public double TauA(IList<T> data)
        {
            var ranked = data
                     .OrderBy(Measure1)
                     .Select((item, index) => new { Data = item, Rank1 = index + 1})
                     .OrderBy(pair => Measure2(pair.Data))
                     .Select((pair, index) => new { pair.Rank1, Rank2 = index + 1 })
                     .ToList();
            var numerator = 0;

            var n = ranked.Count;
            var denominator = n * (n - 1) / 2.0;
            for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
                for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    numerator += Sign(ranked[i].Rank1 - ranked[j].Rank1) 
                               * Sign(ranked[i].Rank2 - ranked[j].Rank2);
                }
            return numerator / denominator;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the Tau-b correlation, which accounts for ties.
        /// 
        ///             n  - n
        ///              c    d
        ///  τ  = -----------------------
        ///   b    _____________________
        ///       / (n  -  n )(n  -  n )
        ///      √    0     1   0     2
        /// 
        /// where:
        ///        n0 = n(n-1)/2
        ///               
        ///        n1 =  Σ  t (t - 1)/2
        ///              i   i  i
        /// 
        ///        n2 =  Σ  t (t - 1)/2
        ///              j   j  j
        /// 
        ///      t[i] = # of ties for the ith group according to measure 1.
        ///      t[j] = # of ties for the jth group according to measure 2.
        ///        nc = # of concordant pairs
        ///        nd = # of discordant pairs
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A correlation value between -1 (perfect reverse correlation)
        ///  and +1 (perfect correlation). 
        /// Zero means uncorrelated. </returns>
        /// <param name="data">Data.</param>
        public double TauB(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            // Compute two Ranks by sorting first by Measure1 and then by Measure2.
            // Group by like values of each in order to handle ties.
            var ranked = data.Select(item => new { M1 = Measure1(item), M2 = Measure2(item) })
                .GroupBy(measures => new { measures.M1 })
                .OrderBy(@group => @group.First().M1)
                .ThenBy(@group => @group.First().M2)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select((@group, groupIndex) => new
                {
                    Measure1Ranked = @group.Select((measure, index) => new { measure.M1, measure.M2 }),
                    Rank = ++groupIndex
                })
                .SelectMany(v => v.Measure1Ranked, (s, i) => new
                {
                    i.M1,
                    i.M2,
                    DenseRank1 = s.Rank
                })
                .GroupBy(measures => new { measures.M2 })
                .OrderBy(@group => @group.First().M2)
                .ThenBy(@group => @group.First().M1)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select((@group, groupIndex) => new
                 {
                     Measure2Ranked = @group.Select((measure, index) => new { measure.M1, measure.M2, measure.DenseRank1 }),
                     Rank = ++groupIndex
                 })
                .SelectMany(v => v.Measure2Ranked, (s, i) => new { i.M1, i.M2, i.DenseRank1, DenseRank2 = s.Rank })                          
                .ToArray();
            if (ranked.Length <= 1)
                return 0; // No data or one data point. Impossible to establish correlation.

            // Now that we have ranked the data, compute the correlation.
            var n = ranked.Count();
            var n0 = n * (n - 1) / 2;
            var n1 = 0;
            var n2 = 0;
            var numerator = 0; // Stores nc - nd as a single value, rather than computing them separately.
            for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
                for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    var iRanked = ranked[i];
                    var jRanked = ranked[j];
                    numerator += Sign(iRanked.DenseRank1 - jRanked.DenseRank1)
                               * Sign(iRanked.DenseRank2 - jRanked.DenseRank2);
                    // Keep track of ties. Because we are running the indices in a triangle,
                    // we automatically get this for n1 and n2: ties * (ties - 1) / 2
                    if (iRanked.M1.CompareTo(jRanked.M1) == 0)
                        n1++;
                    if (iRanked.M2.CompareTo(jRanked.M2) == 0)
                        n2++;
                }
            if (n0 == n1 || n0 == n2)
                return 0; // All ties, so everything as the same rank.
            // Observe that if n1 = n2 = 0, that this formula is identical to Tau-a.
            return numerator / Sqrt((double)(n0 - n1)*(n0 - n2));
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the unit tests in NUnit:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using static System.Math; // New C# 6.0 feature that allows one to import static methods and call them without their class name.

namespace Statistics
{

    [TestFixture]
    public class KendallTauCorrelationTests
    {
        public static int[] OneToTen = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        #region Tau-a

        [Test]
        public void TauA_SameOrder()
        {
            var kendall = new KendallTauCorrelation<int, int>(
                (int value) => value,
                (int value) => value * 10
            );
            Assert.AreEqual(
                1.0,
                kendall.TauA(OneToTen),
                "Numbers that sort in the same order should be perfectly correlated."
            );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TauA_ReverseOrder()
        {
            var kendall = new KendallTauCorrelation<int, int>(
                (int value) => value,
                (int value) => value * -10
            );
            Assert.AreEqual(
                -1.0,
                kendall.TauA(OneToTen),
                "Numbers that sort in reverse order should be perfectly anti-correlated."
            );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TauA_OneSwap()
        {
            var reordered = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            var kendall = new KendallTauCorrelation<int, int>(
                (int value) => value,
                (int value) => reordered[value - 1]
            );
            Assert.AreEqual(
                43.0 / 45.0,
                kendall.TauA(OneToTen),
                0.00001,
                "If a single number is out of place the sequences should be almost perfectly correlated."
            );
        }

        #endregion

        #region Tau-b

        [Test]
        public void TauB_SameOrder()
        {
            var kendall = new KendallTauCorrelation<int,int>(
                (int value) => value, 
                (int value) => value * 10
            );
            Assert.AreEqual(
                1.0, 
                kendall.TauB(OneToTen), 
                "Numbers that sort in the same order should be perfectly correlated."
            );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TauB_ReverseOrder()
        {
            var kendall = new KendallTauCorrelation<int, int>(
                (int value) => value,
                (int value) => value * -10
            );
            Assert.AreEqual(
                -1.0,
                kendall.TauB(OneToTen),
                "Numbers that sort in reverse order should be perfectly anti-correlated."
            );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TauB_OneSwap_NoTies()
        {
            var reordered = new[] { 1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8,9,10 };
            var kendall = new KendallTauCorrelation<int, int>(
                (int value) => value,
                (int value) => reordered[value-1]
            );
            Assert.AreEqual(
                43.0/45.0,
                kendall.TauB(OneToTen),
                0.00001,
                "If a single number is out of place the sequences should be almost perfectly correlated."
            );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TauB_Ties()
        {
            var reordered = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            var kendall = new KendallTauCorrelation<int, int>(
                (int value) => value,
                (int value) => reordered[value - 1]
            );
            Assert.AreEqual(
                42.0 / Sqrt(42.0*45.0),
                kendall.TauB(OneToTen),
                0.00001,
                "Adding a few ties should be almost perfectly correlated."
            );
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

NOTE: This uses the exhaustive, O(N^2) algorithm. There is a more efficient way using a modified mergesort that is N Log N that I have heard mentioned, but I have not seen how it is done.

NOTE: This generic class assumes that both measures return the same data type. It is an easy change to make the class have two generic measure types. They only need to be IComparables. They do not need to be compared to each other.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to measure *how different* they are, but you don't care of where the differences occur, you may use [Kendall's correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient). It gives you a score from -1 (the lists are in reverse order) to +1 (the lists are in the same order).

It basically counts the number of pairs of elements that are in the same order in both lists, and divide by the total number of pairs:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] b = { 3, 4, 1, 8, 6, 7, 2, 5 };

double numer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (a.Length - 1); i++)
  for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
    numer += Math.Sign(a[i] - a[j]) * Math.Sign(b[i] - b[j]);

double tau = numer / (a.Length * (a.Length - 1) / 2);
```

Comment: This appears to be Kendall Tau-a. If your data has ties in rank (because items are not unique), you should use Kendall tau-b, which accounts for ties but is more complicated. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient